# Android App Communication Between App and javascript

Tags: javascript, android, bridge

Is there any way to call java-script function which redirect other page

web url like "www.test.com"

```
function test
{
    $mobile.navigate("Search.php");
}
```

how can i call the java script function from android..it is not working so please help  me.

Comment: So u want to create Simple Plugin which open web url from javascript?

Comment: in Web View i am loading the URL like "www.website.com" there are one javascript function which which navigate the other page using jqeury mobile ..i am calling that function but it is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
```

instead Of `$mobile.navigate("Search.php");`

also you forgot to add `()` in function

:

```
 function test()
{
window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
}
```

Check [new Format](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.navigate/) for mobile navigate.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/g5vAN/) JSFiddle.

**EDIT:**
import your latest jquery mobile js

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Use in js:

`jq.mobile.changePage("Search.php");`

instead of

`$.mobile.changePage("Search.php");`

Comment: But it is jquey mobile view other wise it loading normal view i also can load url directly but there are change the look & feel.So i must call $mobile.navigate("search.php");

Comment: please try to do something for me if possible..Thanks geet

Comment: Use $.mobile.navigate("Search.php");

Comment: stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString this using in IOS version similar this what will be in android..do you have an idea geet ?

Comment: Hi Geet Thanks for help me.It is bug in 4.2.1 below all version...it is properly working with this version..remaining all there are bug..webview.loadurl("javascript:functionname()");

Comment: Actually client provide me just link of its.so we dnt have any PHP code.so we can't update it..Same thing is perfactly working in IOS..

Comment: And android version 4.1.2 it also working proper there are.below all version jquery is not loading...